# PHP Static Variable Issues

Tags: php, variables, static

Ok, Here is a function I am working on. Now mind you I am new to programming, and there is probably more wrong with this then what I am asking. Basically, How do I set the variable:

```
${"MySQL_Connection_" . $MySQL_Connection}
```

And use it when I recall the function with different "Mode(s)". I have tried the use of:

```
static
```

But from what you all are saying. I was grossly misinformed as to the use of it. Here is my "Real Life" Example:

```
<?php
/*

DB_Core_("","","","","");


DB_Close
DB_Core_("DB_Close",<$MySQL_Connection>);

DB_Connection_Status
DB_Core_("DB_Connection_Status",<$MySQL_Connection>);

DB_Connection_Status_Report_Short
DB_Core_("DB_Connection_Status_Report_Short");

DB_Connection_Status_Report_Long
DB_Core_("DB_Connection_Status_Report_Long");

MySQL_Query
DB_Core_("MySQL_Query",
"



"
);

MySQL_Query_Status
DB_Core_("MySQL_Query_Status",<$MySQL_Connection>);

MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Short
DB_Core_("MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Short");

MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Long
DB_Core_("MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Short");

MySQL_Connect
DB_Core_("MySQL_Connect",<$MySQL_Connection>,
                          <$Database_Server_Name>,
                          <$Database_Server_Username>,
                          <$Database_Server_Username_Password>
         );

*/




function DB_Core_ ($DB_Core_Command = "Empty", // Default if not set
                  $DB_Core_Command_Variable_1 = "Empty", // Default if not set
                  $DB_Core_Command_Variable_2 = "Empty", // Default if not set
                  $DB_Core_Command_Variable_3 = "Empty", // Default if not set
                  $DB_Core_Command_Variable_4 = "Empty"  // Default if not set
                 ){

    // Variables
    $MySQL_Connection_Prefix = "MySQL_Connection_";

    // ********************
    // Set Function Mode(s)
    // ********************
    switch ($DB_Core_Command) {
        // ****************************************
        // Function to end connection to a database
        // ****************************************
        case "DB_Close":

            $MySQL_Connection = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_1;

            mysqli_close(${"MySQL_Connection_" . $MySQL_Connection});

            break; // END Function (DB_Close)

        // *****************************************************
        // Function to check the connection status of a database
        // *****************************************************
        case "DB_Connection_Status":

            $MySQL_Connection = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_1;

            if (!${"MySQL_Connection_" . $MySQL_Connection}) {
                    $DB_Connection_Status_Short = 0;
                    $DB_Connection_Status_Long = "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    die();
            } else { 
                    $DB_Connection_Status_Short = 1;
                    $DB_Connection_Status_Long =  "Connected successfully";
            }
            break; // END Function (DB_Connection_Status)

        // ************************************
        // Function to Print MySQL Status Short
        // ************************************
        case "DB_Connection_Status_Report_Short":
            echo $DB_Connection_Status_Short;
            break; // END Function (MySQL_Connection_Status_Report_Short)

        // ***********************************
        // Function to Print MySQL Status Long
        // ***********************************
        case "DB_Connection_Status_Report_Long":
            echo $DB_Connection_Status_Long;
            break; // END Function (MySQL_Connection_Status_Report_Long)

        // ****************************************
        // Function to create a general MySQL Query
        // ****************************************
        case "MySQL_Query":

            $MySQL_Query = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_1;

            $MySQL_Commands = $MySQL_Query;
            break; // END Function (MySQL_Query)

        // *************************************
        // Function to Verify MySQL_Query_Status
        // *************************************
        case "MySQL_Query_Status":

            $MySQL_Connection = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_1;
            if ($DB_Core_Command_Variable_2 = "Empty"){
                $MySQL_Query_Success_Message = "MySQL Query Success..."; // Default if not set
            } else {
                $MySQL_Query_Success_Message = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_2;
            }
            if ($DB_Core_Command_Variable_3 = "Empty"){
                $MySQL_Query_Failure_Message = "MySQL Query Failure: ";  // Default if not set
            } else {
                $MySQL_Query_Failure_Message = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_3;
            }   

            if (mysqli_query(${"MySQL_Connection_" . $MySQL_Connection}, $MySQL_Commands)) 
                    {
                     $MySQL_Query_Status_Short = 1;
                     $MySQL_Query_Status_Long = $MySQL_Query_Success_Message;
                    } 
               else 
                    {
                     $MySQL_Query_Status_Short = 0;
                     $MySQL_Query_Status_Long = $MySQL_Query_Failure_Message . ": " . $MySQL_Commands . "<br>" . mysqli_error(${"MySQL_Connection_" . $MySQL_Connection});
                    }
            break; // END Function (MySQL_Query_Status)

        // ******************************************
        // Function to Print MySQL Query Status Short
        // ******************************************       
        case "MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Short":
            echo $MySQL_Query_Status_Short;
            break; // END Function (MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Short)

        // *****************************************
        // Function to Print MySQL Query Status Long
        // ******************************************   
        case "MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Long":
            echo $MySQL_Query_Status_Long;
            break; // END Function (MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Long)

        // *********************************
        // Function to connect to MySQL
        // *********************************
        case "MySQL_Connect":

            $MySQL_Connection = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_1;
            $Database_Server_Name = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_2;
            $Database_Server_Username = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_3;
            $Database_Server_Username_Password = $DB_Core_Command_Variable_4;                   

            ${"MySQL_Connection_" . $MySQL_Connection} = new mysqli(
                                            $Database_Server_Name,
                                            $Database_Server_Username,
                                            $Database_Server_Username_Password
                                           );
            break; // END Function (DB_Connect)

        // ***************************
        // If No Selection is Declared
        // ***************************
        default:

    } // END Set Function Mode(s)   

} // END - FUNCTION - < $DB_ >

?>
```

Comment: in a class context you couldn't even do that _without_ declaring the var static.

Comment: is there a class involved? i dont understand the use of static outside of OO php

Comment: for the _why_: because it doesn't make sense. In the second example: if $b should be static, it only could be that if also $a was static. A static var depending on a non-static doesn't make sense.

Comment: the only way I could of making this possible is to set `$$c` or `$b` in an init() method. Of course not in a contructor, because you want 'em static. But since the depending once are non-static it again doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I am trying to make some functions for opening and closing MySQL Databases. I need to store the connection in a static variable so that it doesn't disappear once the function has been called Example: DB_("Open"//Command,"Con_1"//Connection Name,"User"//User Name,"Pass"//Password) But to be able to use this with Close command later, The function has to store the Connection.

Comment: i dont see how the comment matches the question. perhaps ask the actual 'real world' question instead?

Comment: Every time I ask a question on here, Its always the same. Rude people who don't really want to help anyone, just try to sound intelligent while making the person asking the question look stupid. I see it on everyone elses posts also. If everyone followed the golden rule, and treated others how they wanted to be treated. There would be practically no responses on this site. It is a real world question. Sorry I didnt put the variables inside a function. Why nitpick and not just try to help? The purpose of a static variable is to store the value after a function has been called. I tried and cant?

Comment: "The purpose of a static variable is to store the value after a function has been called. " that's incorrect, it now sounds like you want `global`

Comment: So from what your all saying. I cannot use static unless it is in a class? I am looking for a way to store a variable inside a function after the function has been called, which is what it states static is for. Why should it matter if I am creating a static variable from a non static one. I just want the static variable to be set by a non static one and then saved to be used later from calling different function commands.

Comment: FROM W3SCHOOLS:

PHP The static Keyword
Normally, when a function is completed/executed, all of its variables are deleted. However, sometimes we want a local variable NOT to be deleted. We need it for a further job.

To do this, use the static keyword when you first declare the variable:

Comment: I was looking for a way to not use globals because everyone says that is a no no, and so that the connection details, once passed to the function, would not be visible outside the function for security reasons.

Comment: There might be the docs from W3Schools a bit, well, irritating. It still makes a big difference if you are in a class context or not. This is why we are also confused (beeing confrontated with a non-real world example).. So the frustration is on both sides. We want to help, but often get unsufficiant information to be able to help, yet spend most of the time to frickle out that information.

Comment: From what I understand til now the solution could be a simple static DBConnection class, that has a method `connect` which sets a static property $connection. Then you can use `DBConnection::connect();` and `DBConnection::$connection` and even implement a `DBConnection::close()`

Comment: But this usecase as you describe it still doesn't explain what for you want to do `static $b = $a;`

Comment: And if you'd had posted the W3School quote in connection of your usecase we would possibly have understood what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

It's weird I keep having to answer my own questions all the time on this site, which defeats the point of even having this site, but I figured out how to create and use classes which make more sense. Wish someone would have said to learn about classes and would have given an example of a class to do this. But again, I figured it out on my own. Thanks again for all your help. Great site. Everyone is so nice and helpful here. Almost like having a party at the IRS.

```
class DB {

/*

// Layout

// $DB1 -> Set_Connection_Pass_Info ("default");
// $DB1 -> Set_Connection_Fail_Info ("default");
// $DB1 -> Connection_Report_Short ();
// $DB1 -> Connection_Report_Long ();
// $DB1 -> Set_Query_Pass_Info ("default");
// $DB1 -> Set_Query_Fail_Info ("default");
// $DB1 -> Query_Report_Short ();
// $DB1 -> Query_Report_Long ();

include "class.php";

$DB1 = new DB;

//  Connection Name - Server Name - User Name - User Password - Database Name: "null" if no Database
$DB1 -> Connect("Connection_1","localhost","root","UserMain1324!","Database_Test_1");

$Connection_1 -> Query (
"Connection_1",
"

"
);

$DB1 -> Close ("Connection_1");
*/

// ****************************************
//          Static Public Variables
// **************************************** 
    static public $MySQL_Connection_ = array();
    //DB::$MySQL_Connection_[$MySQL_Connection] =

    static public $MySQL_Connection_Success_Message = "Connected Successfully or Still Connected";
    //DB::$MySQL_Connection_Success_Message = 

    static public $MySQL_Connection_Failure_Message = "Connection Failed";
    //DB::$MySQL_Connection_Failure_Message = 

    static public $MySQL_Connection_Status_Short = 0;
    //DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Short = 

    static public $MySQL_Connection_Status_Long = "!!! MySQL: NOT CONNECTED !!!";
    //DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Long =

    static public $MySQL_Commands = "null";
    //DB::$MySQL_Commands = 

    static public $MySQL_Query_Success_Message = "MySQL Query Success";
    //DB::$MySQL_Query_Success_Message = 

    static public $MySQL_Query_Failure_Message = "MySQL Query Failure";
    //DB::$MySQL_Query_Failure_Message = 

    static public $MySQL_Query_Status_Short = 0;
    //DB::$MySQL_Query_Status_Short = 

    static public $MySQL_Query_Status_Long = "!!! CANT QUERY: QUERY EMPTY or NOT CONNECTED !!!";
    //DB::$MySQL_Query_Status_Long = 

// ****************************************
// Function to end connection to a database
// ****************************************
    function Close (
        $MySQL_Connection
    )
    {
        DB::$MySQL_Connection_[$MySQL_Connection] = null;

        // Set
        DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Short = 0;
        DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Long = "Was Connected: NOW DISCONNECTED !!!";
    } // END Function (MySQL_Close)

// *****************************************************
// Function to set the $MySQL_Connection_Success_Message
// *****************************************************
function Set_Connection_Pass_Info ($Input_Variable){

    switch ($Input_Variable) {
        case "default":
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_Success_Message = "Connected Successfully";
            break;
        default:
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_Success_Message = $Input_Variable;
    }

} // END function Set_MySQL_Connection_Success_Message

// *****************************************************
// Function to set the $MySQL_Connection_Failure_Message
// *****************************************************
function Set_Connection_Fail_Info ($Input_Variable){

    switch ($Input_Variable) {
        case "default":
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_Failure_Message = "Connection Failed";
            break;
        default:
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_Failure_Message = $Input_Variable;
    }

} // END function $MySQL_Connection_Failure_Message

// ************************************
// Function to Print MySQL Status Short
// ************************************
    function Connection_Report_Short ()
    {
        echo DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Short . "<br> <br>";
    } // END Function (MySQL_Connection_Status_Report_Short)

// ***********************************
// Function to Print MySQL Status Long
// ***********************************
    function Connection_Report_Long ()
    {
        echo DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Long . "<br> <br>";
    } // END Function (MySQL_Connection_Status_Report_Long)

// ****************************************
// Function to create a general MySQL Query
// ****************************************
    function Query (
        $MySQL_Connection,
        // MySQL Query
        $MySQL_Query
    )
    {
        // Create MySQL Query
        // DB::$MySQL_Commands = $MySQL_Query;

        // Create MySQL Query
        try {
            // Prepare statement
            DB::$MySQL_Commands = DB::$MySQL_Connection_[$MySQL_Connection]->prepare($MySQL_Query);

            // execute the query
            DB::$MySQL_Commands->execute();

            // Set 
            DB::$MySQL_Query_Status_Short = 1;
            DB::$MySQL_Query_Status_Long = DB::$MySQL_Query_Success_Message;


            // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
            // echo DB::$MySQL_Commands->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
            }

        // MySQL Query Error Handling
        catch (PDOException $PDOException_Error)
            {
            // Set
            DB::$MySQL_Query_Status_Short = 0;
            DB::$MySQL_Query_Status_Long = DB::$MySQL_Query_Failure_Message . ": " . $MySQL_Query . "<br>" . $PDOException_Error->getMessage();
            }

    } // END Function (MySQL_Query)

// *************************************************
// Function to set the $MySQL_Query_Success_Message;
// *************************************************
function Set_Query_Pass_Info ($Input_Variable){

    switch ($Input_Variable) {
        case "default":
            DB::$MySQL_Query_Success_Message = "MySQL Query Success";
            break;
        default:
            DB::$MySQL_Query_Success_Message = $Input_Variable;
    }

} // END function Set_MySQL_Connection_Success_Message

// *************************************************
// Function to set the $MySQL_Query_Failure_Message;
// *************************************************
function Set_Query_Fail_Info ($Input_Variable){

    switch ($Input_Variable) {
        case "default":
            DB::$MySQL_Query_Failure_Message = "MySQL Query Failure";
            break;
        default:
            DB::$MySQL_Query_Failure_Message = $Input_Variable;
    }

} // END function $MySQL_Connection_Failure_Message

// ******************************************
// Function to Print MySQL Query Status Short
// ******************************************
    function Query_Report_Short ()
    {
        echo DB::$MySQL_Query_Status_Short . "<br> <br>";
    } // END Function (MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Long)

// *****************************************
// Function to Print MySQL Query Status Long
// *****************************************
    function Query_Report_Long ()
    {
        echo DB::$MySQL_Query_Status_Long . "<br> <br>";
    } // END Function (MySQL_Query_Status_Report_Long)

// Main function //

// ****************************
// Function to connect to MySQL
// ****************************
    function Connect(
        $MySQL_Connection,
        $Database_Server_Name,
        $Database_Server_Username,
        $Database_Server_Username_Password,
        $Database_Name // Set to "null" if not connecting to a database
    )
    {
        // Create Connection
        try {
            // Add database portion of cononect statement if connecting to a database
            if($Database_Name = "null"){
                $Database_Connection_Addon = "";
            } else {
                $Database_Connection_Addon = ";dbname=$Database_Name";
            }

            // Create Connection
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_[$MySQL_Connection] = new PDO("mysql:host=$Database_Server_Name" . "$Database_Connection_Addon", $Database_Server_Username, $Database_Server_Username_Password);

            // Connection Attributes
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_[$MySQL_Connection]->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // Set
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Short = 1;
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Long =  DB::$MySQL_Connection_Success_Message;

            }

        // Connection Error Handling
        catch (PDOException $PDOException_Error)
            {
            // Set
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Short = 0;
            DB::$MySQL_Connection_Status_Long = DB::$MySQL_Connection_Failure_Message . ": " . $PDOException_Error->getMessage();
            }

    } // END Function (MySQL_Connect)   

} // END CLASS (DB)
```